# Model to ViewModel mappings not passed to child objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inheritance, reflection, automapper

I'm new with AutoMapper but I've read a few tutorials and decided to try it.
In those tutorials there was a good idea which I decided to adopt. The authir suggested that the mapping code for the view model should stay in the view model and not in the AutoMapper configuration. This will make it smaller and easily readable:

Here are the base files to do this using reflections, **AutoMapperConfiguration**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

using AutoMapper;

public class AutoMapperConfig
{
    private Assembly assembly;

    public AutoMapperConfig(Assembly assembly)
    {
        this.assembly = assembly;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        var types = this.assembly.GetExportedTypes();

        LoadStandardMappings(types);

        LoadCustomMappings(types);
    }

    private static void LoadStandardMappings(IEnumerable<Type> types)
    {
        var maps = from t in types
                   from i in t.GetInterfaces()
                   where i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IMapFrom<>) && !t.IsAbstract && !t.IsInterface
                   select new { Source = i.GetGenericArguments()[0], Destination = t };

        foreach (var map in maps)
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap(map.Source, map.Destination);
        }
    }

    private static void LoadCustomMappings(IEnumerable<Type> types)
    {
        var maps = from t in types
                   from i in t.GetInterfaces()
                   where typeof(IHaveCustomMappings).IsAssignableFrom(t) && !t.IsAbstract && !t.IsInterface
                   select (IHaveCustomMappings)Activator.CreateInstance(t);

        foreach (var map in maps)
        {
            map.CreateMappings(Mapper.Configuration);
        }
    }
}

public interface IMapFrom<T>
{
}

public interface IHaveCustomMappings
{
    void CreateMappings(IConfiguration configuration);
}
```

The ***IMapFrom*** and ***IHaveCustom*** interfaces are here only to mark the mapping classes. Now we come to the interesting part. When I do for example a class like the following

```
public class BasicAddressViewModel : IHaveCustomMappings
{ 
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Label { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Number")]
    public string Location { get; set; }

    public void CreateMappings(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var map = configuration.CreateMap<Address, BasicAddressViewModel>();
        map.ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id));
        map.ForMember(dest => dest.Label, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Label));
        map.ForMember(dest => dest.Location, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Location));
    }
}
```

I'm setting the mappings in the **CreateMappings** method but if I decide to use this class as a parent those mappings will not be available to my child class and therefor I will have to reuse the same code for all my children classes:

```
public class IndexAddressViewModel : BasicAddressViewModel
{
    public void CreateMappings(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var map = configuration.CreateMap<Address, IndexAddressViewModel >();
        map.ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id));
        map.ForMember(dest => dest.Label, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Label));
        map.ForMember(dest => dest.Location, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Location));
    }
}
```

In reality what I want to achieve is this

```
public class IndexAddressViewModel : BasicAddressViewModel
{

}
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a protected method in your base class that creates the custom mappings

```
protected virtual IMappingExpression<BasicAddressViewModel, TDestination> CreateBaseMappings<TDestination>(IMappingExpression<BasicAddressViewModel, TDestination> mappingExpression) 
    where TDestination : BasicAddressViewModel
```

and make your `CreateMappings(IConfiguration configuration)` method `virtual` so you can `override` it in your derived class and call the base `CreateBaseMappings` method that returns `IMappingExpression<BasicAddressViewModel, TDestination>` which means you can add more mappings for other members

**EDIT**
I found a better solution. :)
Since AutoMapper 2.0 you can use the `IncludeBase<BaseModel, BaseViewModel>()` to call the mapping for the base type. So the new solution is to make your `CreateMappings(IConfiguration configuration)` method `virtual` in the base ViewModel class and override it in your derived class where you call:

```
configuration.CreateMap().IncludeBase();
```